# How to combine duplicated rows in tableau

Tags: concatenation, tableau-api, rows

I need to remove duplicate rows from showing in the tableau layout.

I cant share too much data, but the image added shows, outlined in blue that the rows are a duplication of each other and so showing the same data twice.

I've tried concatenation but I can only get this to work for one level.[image]

Public workbook

https://public.tableau.com/profile/jaime.hutchins#!/vizhome/DuplicatedRows/Dashboard1

Comment: Those rows aren't actually duplicates in the data itself. The [what looks to be] department, times, and ownership differ. Because the rows differ in the data, there will need to be some conditional amendment (with calculated fields) to the data. __What is your desired output?__ Considering if you are to combine your blue square data, you will lose one or the other of 'Owned' or 'Assigned' rows.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, to help I've created a public work book with basically the exact as close to live as possible.

You can see with reference 103 rows after the Open Stage are duplicated, I would like combine them back together.

The link to the public workbook is:
https://public.tableau.com/profile/jaime.hutchins#!/vizhome/DuplicatedRows/Dashboard1